# Closed form of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{{n\choose k}e^{-(2k+1)x}\over \cosh^n(x)}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

How do I find the closed form of $(1)?$

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n\choose k}e^{-(2k+1)x}\over \cosh^n(x)}\mathrm dx=F(n)\tag1$$
>   Where $n\ge1$

F(n) seems only to give rational number according to numerical observation.

I was able to find the closed form of similar to $(1)$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n\choose k}e^{-(2k+1)x}\over \cosh(x)}\mathrm dx={2^n-1\over n}\tag2$$

Where $n\ge1$

Others

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x}\over \cosh(x)}\mathrm dx=\ln{2}\tag3$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{2e^{-2x}\over \cosh(x)}\mathrm dx=4-\pi\tag4$$

[The idea came from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101702/continued-fraction-for-some-integrals-by-ramanujan)

Comment: Are you sure that its n and not k in the summation? If its just n take everything which is not summing over k out of the sum. The sum of the binomial coefficients is equal to $2^n$. You will only have to integrate the rest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use that

$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k$$

Hence

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n\choose k}e^{-(2k+1)x}\over \cosh^n(x)} = \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-x}(1+e^{-2x})^n}{\cosh^n(x)}\,dx$$

Now use that

$$\cosh(x) = \frac{1+e^{-2x}}{2e^{-x}}$$

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{2^ne^{-x(1+n)}(1+e^{-2x})^n}{(1+e^{-2x})^n}\,dx = 2^n\int^\infty_0 e^{-(n+1)x}\,dx = \frac{2^n}{n+1}$$

Comment: The result should be $2^n/(n+1)$: the $\cosh^n x$ contributes $e^{-nx}$ to the bottom integrals, not $e^{-2nx}$.

Comment: @AntonioDJC, Yes thanks.